# Change of files/image location to a new organized structure

Tags: updating, files

I would like to clean up safely the existing files Drupal 7 structure and change the location of my existing Files/Image to a new organized structure e.g. in files/content-type/year/node-id

Would File Path do this safely with its retroactive update, or is there another module out there?

Comment: Assuming you're talking about File (Field) Paths, I'd recommend not using it - it has a lot of deep-seated problems. I haven't come across a module that solves this problem properly in many years of Drupal development.

Comment: @Clive I'd love to hear more of your opinion about it when you say deep-seated problems! I was planing to use this module as well for a specific requirement.